# Is there a way in mongodb to $project the array of all the regex matches for a given field?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find all the matches for a regex in a mongodb aggregate query for a field called `title`. I would like to get all the matches in a projected field via $project.

I have already looked into $text operator for text searching, but that is not what I am looking for.

Sample documents in **items** collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ceb898f12a765d79aead953"),
    "title": "This is the text of the title field"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce7dc269e03d7714c84aa43"),
    "title": "Yet another sample for title field"
}
```

Then I run the following query:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      title: /t./g
    }
  }
]);
```

The above query matches both the documents, which is the expected behavior.

However, I would like the following output:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ceb898f12a765d79aead953"),
  "title": "This is the text of the title field",
  "generatedField": ["th", "te", "t ", "th", "ti", "tl"]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ce7dc269e03d7714c84aa43"),
  "title": "Yet another sample for title field",
  "generatedField": ["t ", "th", "ti", "tl"]
}
```

I would assume the query would be something like below. The code in parenthesis is what I am looking for:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      title: /t./g
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      generatedField: (code to generate javascript equivalent of $title.match(/t./g))
    }
  }
]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide sample data and an expected result example?

Comment: I can't test / make a solution right now, but you should look at [for each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/index.html) and function

Comment: As of MongoDB 4.0.10, there is no method to project what you want. You would need to add `generatedField` from within your application instead.